# CheckComboBoxEdit Devexpress Control

Tags: .net, winforms, devexpress

It is possible when using the DevExpress `CheckComboBoxEdit` to bind the check box to a property of a class? I have this class:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

I want it to behave so that if the `IsActive` property is true, then the check box of that object is set to be checked. I'll bind the `Id` and `Name` to `DisplayName` and `ValueMember`, but I can't bind `IsActive` to any properties.  How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with any control. You need to bind IsActive Property to your checkbox's "checked" property as below.

[image]

With this binding whenever your property is changed true to false it will reflect on checkbox automatically.

Comment: whith which control You can do this operation? I do not see this option(checked) in DevExpress CheckComboBoxEdit .